# "Land rushing" new technology basic questions: does anyone care?

Tags: discussion, questions, reputation

Every Stack Overflow user has encountered a question with many thousands of upvotes that could have been answered by a brief look at a man page (several git questions fall into this class).

While I don't mean to suggest that such questions aren't useful, I do wonder if there are some users who "land rush" new topics, asking very basic questions about new technologies with the hope of accruing massive reputation. Of course, distinguishing between a "sincere" question and one that is posted merely to accrue reputation is probably tricky (although looking at users who have many such questions in widely disparate topics would be a clue).

Do the Stack Overflow managers look for this? Do they even care? Should anyone care?

(Note: it bothers me but perhaps I am in the minority.)

Comment: Is this meant to be specific to Stack Overflow (the programming Q&A site) or general to the whole Stack Exchange network?

Comment: If a user posts a question that is deemed useful by many, is that really a *bad* thing? Do we really want to ascribe sinister motives when, in the end, it helps grow the knowledge base?

Comment: Hover your mouse over the upvote button. Do you see it prompting you to press it if the content is useful to you? Why should folks not get imaginary internet points for posting something that was useful for so many? What is the possible downside?

Comment: Perhaps you'd spend your time better wondering why it bothers you so much.

Comment: Users posting basic questions about emerging tech is not only fine, but crucial to the mission of SO (regardless of whether the company shares it or not): to build a library of answers to every practical programming problem there is. Their intentvdoes not matter as long as the bebefits do not outweigh the drawbacks.

Comment: That said, amassing enourmous amount of rep from a single (or just few) posts is a well known problem and *is* a big issue. But it is only an issue because it is tightly coupled to curation tools (which is a contradiction in terms) - if the company was to finally untie them, this issue would cease to exist that instant.

Comment: "Do the Stack Overflow managers look for this?" - For the company more popular content = more ad revenue. So I wouldn't expect the company to go out of their way to block the money makers.

Answer (score 26):

So users are trying to game the system by posting actually useful and on-topic content?

[image]

Comment: Reminds me of an off-site discussion I saw. The topic was that many questions were closed on SO. And one user found a trick - by *posting the wrong code* they'd get replies with fixes. Claiming it's [Cunningham's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward_Cunningham#%22Cunningham's_Law%22) in effect. And probably missing that a reproducible example is actually required when somebody has a debugging question.

Answer (score 20):

As long as they're doing a good job of asking the question, not only do I not object to this, but I actively welcome it, even if the asker's motive is, as you put it, *"merely to accrue reputation"*.

Often *sincere* people, who are genuinely struggling with a beginner-level problem, will do a rubbish job of asking about it, and if their rubbish question is the first one posted about the topic then we may end up with it coming top in Google results forever. Ways to do a bad job of asking include:

- Asking a question that is simultaneously a how-to question and a debugging question
- Including a bunch of the asker's tangentially-relevant misconceptions about how the language works in the question
- Waffling for multiple paragraphs when the question could've been asked in two sentences

If someone who is asking such a question purely for the rep nonetheless does a good job of asking, and thereby gets a succinct and clear question to the top of the results that people see for the question on Google, then they are still helping the site and the internet, regardless of what their motivations were.