# Make it clear that high score of the old basic questions doesn’t guarantee a similar question will be welcomed today

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I believe some newcomers could be tricked by the high score of the old questions into thinking that questions like “how do I increment variable in [language]” (okay, that’s exaggeration but you got my point) is valid, and hence they could go and ask a similarly easy to answer question expecting it to be well-received.

Most of them miss the fact that something that is easy-googlable today may not have been so easy-googlable in the past, or just haven’t been asked so many times back in 2009-2010.

Something should be done to specifically address this. Sometimes rather good formatted questions pop in the list, yet so easy-to-find —- I don’t believe that user wasn’t able to find that information over the web, but rather thought that they could also get some upvotes with an easy question.

---

Of course, *I don’t mean that it’s bad to ask easy questions of any kind*.

How easy is too easy, though? A question on splitting a string in JavaScript is not interesting, but if a new language comes out (like it happened with swift, for example), then it’s of course absolutely okay to ask basic questions. The point is, once it’s easily searchable, it has been most certainly asked, but some users would still ask it because they thought that a high score is somewhat guaranteed. It’s not really the point that it would be closed as duplicate anyway. My point is: I believe that high score of basic questions from the past tricks the users into thinking they could ask a similar question in a similar area.

*oh! it will be ironic if my post is an easy-to-find dupe…*

Comment: [Recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71887946/is-there-a-javascript-like-operator-for-increment-in-python)

Comment: Basic questions are actually fine on SO. Whether they're trivially findable via a google search doesn't matter so long as it hasn't been asked on SO before. In fact, many of the trivially findable questions are only trivial to find because they've been asked on SO at some point.

Comment: generally... when someone asks such a question it's because they don't know it's easily googleable, or it isn't for them because they don't know what they're looking for.

Comment: I’m sorry, I must have misformulated the problem, please check edit

Comment: "*... some users would still ask it because they thought that a high score is somewhat guaranteed.*" What are you basing this on? In my experience, as mentioned by KevinB as well, users who ask basic questions are typically doing it because they want to know the answer themselves, and not because they want to earn lots of rep from it.

Comment: @cigien I may be mistaken, but I frequently see questions that can be answered with a couple of top search results if one pasts a question title in the search bar. I’m often confused why would one ask such a question when it’s easier and faster to just google for existing solutions. Like, who would want to spend some time to write a question instead of googling its title?

Comment: That does happen, but the solution to that is different than for people purposely posting useless questions because other *now* useless questions posted in the past were well received. Obviously the system should encourage people to do their research prior to posting

Comment: Laziness/incompetence are both better explanations for such behavior than greed. Without evidence to the contrary, I'm inclined to assume it's one of the former. Also, if greed for rep is the motivation, that wouldn't explain the same user repeatedly asking basic questions (which happens often) since they don't get much rep from the first instance. The other reasons do explain this behavior though.

Comment: Related: ["Land rushing" new technology basic questions: does anyone care?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415195/8967612)

Comment: Related: *[Introducing Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/)*

Comment: Some *are* welcomed. From yesterday: *[Do all pointers have the same size in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71870205/)*. 27 upvotes at this point. I find it hard to believe this is not duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

I guess this depends on your definition of "welcomed".

If by "welcomed" you mean "isn't a dupe" then there's really no good way to make that clear to someone besides closing their question as a dupe.

If by "welcomed" you mean "won't be downvoted" then there's really no good way to determine that either, since people tend to *like* downvoting duplicates if they really are the kind that you could "just Google", for one's given definition of "just Google".

If by "welcomed" you mean "on-topic", that's a bit of a gray area.  We don't really care so much about if a question is basic or not, so long as it's not a dupe and is clearly and concisely scoped.

Nothing we say or do can guarantee that a question will get an upvote, but there's a *lot* about a question that we could observe that would merit a downvote.  Not much we can do about that.

Comment: It is, indeed, my area! Something of a soapbox, actually. The rules are quite clear, based on our inherent principles and goals, as outlined in the [tour]. Basic questions are *just fine*; in fact, they're a *useful* addition to our knowledge base. It's *only* a problem if it's something that is an easily-findable duplicate (because then you aren't contributing a useful signpost), and we have a built-in solution for that problem: closing it as a duplicate. (I realize this is almost exactly what you said. I just don't know why you consider the topicality of basic questions a "gray area".)

Comment: @CodyGray: It probably isn't, it's just that for whatever reason the crowd is incredibly fickle about what they see is on topic or not, which leads to questions getting closed unnecessarily and OPs storming off while we desperately try to fix the situation after they've become disillusioned and disengaged. Everyone has different feelings about what constitutes a "basic" question.